# How to move all subfolders to another folder preserving tree?

Tags: vbscript

I want to move all **subfolders** with files, preserving the tree, located in "V:\FTP", to "V:\FTP\Completed" using VBScript.

I want to exclude "V:\FTP\TEMP1" and "V:\FTP\TEMP2" from moving.

I have a script moving all **files** in "V:\FTP" to "V:\FTP\Completed" excluding "V:\FTP\folder.jpg":

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("V:\FTP").Files
For Each objFile In objFolder
    If objFile.Name <> "folder.jpg" Then
        objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Path, "V:\FTP\Completed\"
    End If
Next
```

My Problem is I don't understand how to do the same with folders.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/ch28h2s7%28v%3dvs.84%29#working-with-folders). You're looking for the [`SubFolders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/e1dthkks%28v%3dvs.84%29) property and the [`MoveFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/465s5y8s%28v%3dvs.84%29) method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation, here my working script:

```
Dim fso, objFol, objMoveFol

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFol = fso.GetFolder("V:\FTP")

For Each objMoveFol In objFol.SubFolders

If objMoveFol.Name <> "Completed" and objMoveFol.Name <> "TEMP2" and objMoveFol.Name <> "TEMP1" Then

    objMoveFol.move "V:\FTP\Completed\"
End If

Next
```